# Java 8 on Windows 10 - CLASSPATH does not work

Tags: java, windows-10, classpath

Windows 10 1803 64-bit, Java JRE 8. No JDK installed.

I have a .jar in a folder:

```
c:\users\myuser\KickAssembler\KickAss.jar
```

Under System environment variables I have the CLASSPATH as:

```
c:\users\myuser\KickAssembler\
```

At a command prompt the CLASSPATH is set (checked with ECHO).

At a prompt when I try:

```
java -jar KickAss.jar
```

It returns:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile KickAss.jar
```

If I CD into the directory first, then run it, it works fine. So it looks like CLASSPATH is not being used somehow. I have added the location into the standard Windows PATH also, still doesn't work.

Different combinations of casing for the filename doesn't work. Windows is set to show hidden files. It can't be a permissions issue because it works when I change into the directory first.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: In system environment you place path to `java_folder\bin`, not path of `your_app.jar`. After that, check in `cmd` with `java -version`. If get error some is still wrong.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what I'm trying to do. It has no problem finding JAVA.EXE

Comment: I think you misunderstand the utility of classpath. Classpath is path where java can find the dependency jars. It has nothing to do with the primary jar that you intend to run.

Comment: "The class path tells JDK tools and applications where to find third-party and user-defined classes -- that is, classes that are not Java extensions or part of the Java platform. The class path needs to find any classes you've compiled with the javac compiler -- its default is the current directory to conveniently enable those classes to be found."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#env_var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLASSPATH is used to define the path from which Java will load classes. CLASSPATH can contain folders and JAR files, such as: **C:\mybin;c:\myjars\some.jar** This classpath would load any fully qualified class file residing in or beneath **c:\mybin** and any fully qualified class within **c:\myjars\some.jar**. CLASSPATH will not allow JAVA to find your JAR file as you are expecting when using the -jar switch, it does not search for any JAR file along the classpath, it will only look in the ones explicitly stated in the CLASSPATH and then only for class files within them. Note, fully qualified means **package + class**, such as: **com.myorg.somepackage.someclass**, not just **someclass**.

As you observed, if you are in the folder where kickass.jar resides your command line works as the JAR file is present. If you fully reference the JAR file while executing the command from another folder the command line should work as well.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html for more detail on how CLASSPATH works. It is important to have a solid understanding of CLASSPATH when using JAVA.